# Method for converting an pine script indicator to a screener?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have an indicator that plots an UP arrow as soon as the desired condition is met. With the help of a screener I want to be alerted about all those stocks where this up arrow has been plotted in the last candle. is it possible?

I want to apply this logic on screener so that a wide number of stocks can be scanned. if that is not an option i would request the community to help me adding a table with pre defined stocks on which this indicator can run and give output.

```
//@version=4
study("AO Histogram Track", overlay=true)

var float prevAO = 0
var bool track = false

// track candlestick values
var float trackedOpen = na
var float trackedHigh = na
var float trackedLow = na
var float trackedClose = na
var int trackedHighBarIndex = na

// calculate Awesome Oscillator
ao = sma(hl2, 5) - sma(hl2, 34)

// track AO histogram above zero
if (ao > 0)
    prevAO := ao
    track := true

// track candlestick values while AO histogram is above zero
if (track)
    trackedOpen := open
    if high > trackedHigh or na(trackedHigh)
        trackedHigh := high
        trackedHighBarIndex := bar_index
        trackedLow := low // update trackedLow when a new high is found
    trackedClose := close

// check for crossunder of AO histogram
if (prevAO > 0 and ao < 0)
    track := false

// define a variable to track the most recent yellow line price
var float yellowLinePrice = na

// plot horizontal line at trackedLow or midpoint of candlestick with highest high value when tracking stops and update yellowLinePrice
if not track and not na(trackedHigh)
    // check if total number of histogram bars between crossover and crossunder is greater than or equal to 5
    if bar_index - trackedHighBarIndex >= 10 
        linePrice = trackedLow // default to plotting line at trackedLow
        if abs(high[1] - low[1]) * 2 < abs(trackedHigh - trackedLow) or abs(high[2] - low[2]) * 2 < abs(trackedHigh - trackedLow)
            linePrice := (trackedHigh + trackedLow) / 2 // plot line at midpoint of candlestick with highest high value if size condition is met
        line.new(trackedHighBarIndex, linePrice, trackedHighBarIndex + 20, linePrice, xloc=xloc.bar_index, color=color.purple, width=4)
        yellowLinePrice := linePrice
    trackedHigh := na

// plot an up arrow on the chart when the current market price closes above the most recent yellow line price
plotchar(crossover(close, yellowLinePrice), char='↑', location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.tiny)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently no possible way to use the screener to do that, however you can use the request security function to gather data and check the condition for multiple stocks at the same time and use a table to view it.

Here’s an example of an open source script that does something similar with candlestick combos.

[example screener script](https://www.tradingview.com/script/0KuZ2PIg-Candle-Combo-Screener/)